# Identify PCI/PII data in log files

Tags: logs

Is there a tool available which can scan and tell me if there is a PCI/PII data being logged by the application. I basically want to make sure that my team members are not logging any PCI/PII data. So is there any standard tool available.

I found this tool called MITRE but it only works for PII data but I need to check for both PCI and PII data

The tool should be for Linux, or a library for Java and Nodejs. Currently I'm looking for open-source tools. But can evaluate paid once if nothing is there in OpenSource/Free. We already have Sumologic for logs and Fortify for security scans.

Thanks, 
Amol

Comment: Thanks, Amol – I've integrated that with your question post and will cleanup above comments now. You might wish to [edit] your post once more and add some links for reference (e.g. MITRE, Sumologic and Fortify) for those who want to get the "big picture". Good luck!

Comment: Please define PCI.